# Serilog doesn't work in Reliable Actor Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, actor, serilog

I have two Service Fabric application. The first is an Asp.Net Core Service Fabric, the second is an Actor Service that run with timer.

Both are set up with Serilog. The Asp.Net Core work very well. no problem there, but the second service, Actor Service, I use the same configurations and same nuget packages but Serilog doesn't save any log.

**Add Config**

```
<add key="serilog:using:Seq" value="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.serverUrl" value="http://*****" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.apiKey" value="UfKpKLicyZI3hGe7Vc" />
    <add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\File-{Date}.txt" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
```

Comment: Can you share how you are setting up Serilog in the Actor Services?

Comment: Edited with set up

Comment: Okay there's the config, but also show how you initialize Serilog in the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause here is that the Serilog `Logger` is not being `Dispose()`d before the process hosting the actor shuts down (if you're setting up the static `Log` class instead of using a logger instance directly, this is achieved with `Log.CloseAndFlush()`).

Comment: Thank you man. It's works to me. I suposed the actor was disposed before Serilog work, then now I call CloseAndFlush before finish the executation and it works... Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply. Helps to mark the question as answered so that others know. Cheers!

Comment: @novac Remember to use the green check mark next to the answer if it solved your problem. It lets others know that your issue is solved, and gives Nicholas imaginary Internet points that unlock real privileges on Stack Overflow so he can have more tools to contribute with.